# Extracting file basename without extension

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to list all `pdf` files recursively in my directory using `find` command:

```
find -name "*.pdf" > all_pdf.txt
```

output is correct which is as shown (all_pdf.txt):

```
./C++/data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani.pdf
./C++/C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.).pdf
./C++/Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition).pdf
./C++/Essential_C++.pdf
./C++/Stawww.free-ebooks-cloud.com --nley B. Lippman - C++ Primer, Fourth Edition-signed.pdf
./C++/c_primer_5th_edition.pdf
./C++/C++ for Dummies 5th Ed.pdf
./C++/C++ Programming for the Absolute Beginner, Second Edition.pdf
./C++/c++_by_balaguruswamy/balagurusami_objectoriented_programming_cPP.pdf
./C++/c++_by_balaguruswamy/alagurusami_objectoriented_programming_cCh8to10__(1).pdf
./C++/c++_by_balaguruswamy/balagurusami_objectoriented_programming_cCh1to5__.pdf
./C++/c++_by_balaguruswamy/balagurusami_objectoriented_programming_cCh5to7__.pdf
./C++/c++_by_balaguruswamy/lagurusami_objectoriented_programming_cCh11to17__.pdf
./JQUERY/jQuery UI.pdf
./JQUERY/prototype-151-api.pdf
./JQUERY/jquery_succinctly.pdf
./JQUERY/learning_jquery_3rd_edition.pdf
./JQUERY/pro_php_and_jquery.pdf
./JQUERY/Learning jQuery, 4th Edition.pdf
./JQUERY/codeschool_try_jquery.pdf
./JQUERY/jQuery Game Development Essentials.pdf
./JQUERY/Manning.jQuery.in.Action.2nd.Edition.Jun.2010.pdf
./JQUERY/cdn.bitbucket.org-JQuery_Documentation.pdf
./JQUERY/Professional jQuery.pdf
```

but my requirement is to list only `basename` of all files without its extension like:

```
c_primer_5th_edition.pdf
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.).pdf
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition).pdf
...
```

how to do that by providing `filename` (in this case 'all_pdf.txt') as argument to `basename` command.

Comment: The term "extension" usually refers to the trailing portion of a file name, following the final `.` (`pdf` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `sed`

To remove the directory names from every line in `all_pdf.txt`, use:

```
$ sed -e 's|.*/||' all_pdf.txt 
data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani.pdf
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.).pdf
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition).pdf
Essential_C++.pdf
[...snip...]
```

If in addition, you want to remove the file *extension*, then use:

```
$ sed -e 's|.*/||' -e 's|\.pdf$||' all_pdf.txt 
data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.)
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition)
Essential_C++
[...snip...]
```

#### Using `grep`

```
$ grep -o '[^/]*$' all_pdf.txt 
data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani.pdf
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.).pdf
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition).pdf
Essential_C++.pdf
[...snip...]
```

To also remove the `.pdf` extension:

```
$ grep -Po '[^/]*(?=.pdf$)' all_pdf.txt 
data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.)
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition)
Essential_C++
[...snip...]
```

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*\//, "")} 1' all_pdf.txt 
data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani.pdf
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.).pdf
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition).pdf
Essential_C++.pdf
[...snip...]
```

To also remove the `.pdf` extension:

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*\//, ""); sub(/\.pdf$/, "")} 1' all_pdf.txt 
data structures , algorithms and applications in c++ by sartraj sahani
C++Complete Reference (3rd Ed.)
Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language(Third Edition)
Essential_C++
[...snip...]
```